# Non-linear ODE from closed-loop system and Response

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, control-systems

I started using Mathematica 12 and ran into difficulties. Namely, I want to compare the results of the calculation of a closed system from Simulink and in Mathematica.
I rummaged around a bit on the Internet and found an implementation of nonlinear state spaces. Having written my code, I encountered a difficulty, namely the implementation of integration.
Help me to understand.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html

[image]

[image]

```
nsys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{u Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 2] == Integral[Subscript[x, 1]]}, {Subscript[x, 2]}}, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}, u]
OutputResponse[nsys, Sin[t], {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[%, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following to get the `NonlinearStateSpaceModel`

```
nsys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[x2'[t] == u[t] x2[t], x2[t], u[t], x2[t], t]
```

> [image]

And then simulate it

```
Plot[Evaluate@OutputResponse[{nsys, 0.0001}, Sin[t], {t, 0, 20}], {t, 0, 20}]
```

> [image]

Alternatively, you can use `SystemsConnectionsModel` and `SystemsModelMerge` to get `nsys`

```
product5 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, u1  u2}, {}, {u1, u2}];
integrator4 = TransferFunctionModel[1/s, s];
SystemsModelMerge[SystemsConnectionsModel[{product5, integrator4}, 
       {{1, 1} -> {2, 1}, {2, 1} -> {1, 2}}, {{1, 1}}, {{2, 1}}]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Dear Suba Thomas, thanks for your reply.
The results are similar to what Simulink produces.
Another question is whether it is possible to obtain a differential equation describing the output signal from a nonlinear state space. I mean the Nonlinear Article-Spas transformation -> Differential equation.
And that means "gray dot" under the symbol x1. This notation is not known to me.

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can do something along the lines of `With[{res = Normal[nsys]}, {Thread[D[res[[2]], res[[5]]] == res[[1, 1]]], res[[1, 2]]}]`. The formal variables (`\[FormalT]`, `\[FormalX]`, etc) are kind of special variables. If you assign something to them it could mess up the results.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of this expression. Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Could you clarify what it is that you are not understanding?

Comment: In principle, I feel that i can figure out the code by reading the directory on the Wolphram website. Only one thing I want to clarify - what does the "gray dot" mean under the symbol x1.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264

Comment: Dear Suba Thomas, i need help again. In the examples of the use of "Mathematics" there is a Feedback Linearize and StateTransformLinearize, but they are given for affine systems. Is it possible to make a similar linearization for my system, the modeling of which was made in this topic, as well as for other nonlinear systems?