# Experiments with Feedback Linearization and StateTransformLinearization in Mathematica

Tags: nonlinear, control-systems, differential-geometry

I have some nonlinear system, and i have three big question:
[Non-linear ODE from closed-loop system and Response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203860/non-linear-ode-from-closed-loop-system-and-response/203883?noredirect=1#comment527112_203883)
1. how correctly use such terms, like "Feedback Linearization and StateTransform Linearization" for this case, but in Mathematica they use for affine systems. There exist tranform from clearly nonlinear system to affine?
2. is there terms relate to differential geometry control?
3. is it possible to do in Mathematica a transformation to the Brunovsky form?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376921/differential-geometry-for-nonlinear-control-theory for several text suggetions. as to your question 2.

Comment: Morbo, thank you. These book i have read already.
Not all of them are useful, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The example in the question you linked to is an affine system. It turns out to be not completely linearizable by state-transformation alone, but it is feedback linearizable. These techniques are for affine systems only.

   ```
   FeedbackLinearize[AffineStateSpaceModel[x2'[t] == u[t] x2[t], x2[t], u[t], x2[t], t], 
   Automatic, "LinearSystem"]
   ```

   > [image]
2. I don't follow your question.
3. `FeedbackLinearize`by default gives the Burnovsky form if possible. There is an [example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeedbackLinearize.html#333778624), and see the last [item](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeedbackLinearize.html#412984548) in the details section of the `FeedbackLinearize` ref page.

Comment: The OP means Nonlinear control schemes where Diff geom. plays a roll, Namely Geometric control.

Comment: I do not quite understand, is this only possible for affine systems?

Comment: @AndySol, Yes...

Comment: If the system is not initially affine, can it be converted to affine?

Comment: Yes, but because there is no systematic way to do it, as a user you have to manually do that, if possible. For example, if the system is $x'=-x + x u^2$, you can choose a new input $v=u^2$, to make the system affine $x'=-x + x v$.

Comment: Therefore, affine systems are those that are linear with respect to the input signal.

Comment: @AndySol, Yes...

Comment: Mr. Suba Thomas, how well do you know geometric control theory? What opportunities does it provide in addition to new linearization methods? (which is already a lot)